# How to pass string[] value to .net api from postman

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've a endpoint like below

```
 [HttpPost("GetSchoolsDetails")]
    public ActionResult<SchoolModel> GetSchoolsDetails(string[] SchoolsUuid)
    {
     //some code
    }
```

And i tried to call this endpoint from postman like this
[image]

but i'm getting Cannot deserialize the current JSON object error
please Let me know the better way to try .. thanks

Comment: Have you tried passing only an array instead of enclosing it into a braces.. Body enclosed in curly brackets will be considered as JSON object. Your endpoint is expecting an array of guids(string).

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

```
["AA","BB"]
```

[image]

result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change two things from above:

1. Add [`[FromBody]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody) attribute to the parameter of `GetSchoolsDetails` endpoint.

> Use of `[FromBody]`: To force Web API to read a simple type from the
> request body

```
   [HttpPost("GetSchoolsDetails")]
   public ActionResult<SchoolModel> GetSchoolsDetails([FromBody] string[] SchoolsUuid)
   {
       //some code
   }
```

2. Now pass array of `SchoolsUuid` directly from postman.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By calling this way it is reaching to the endpoint
[image]

Answer (score 0):

in body of postman set:

```
[
  "string1",
  "string2"
]
```

[image]

I tested this method and it works correctly. hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. I tested this method and it works correctly.

[image: Postman screenshot Setup here:]

[image: Output screenshot view here]